# How to use multiple imported modules?

Tags: python

I am using PyCharm with Python 3.4 and trying to use https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr . When I try to import pytumblr I get this error, "ImportError: No module named 'helpers'". In the `__init__.py` file,

```
from helpers import validate_params, validate_blogname
from request import TumblrRequest
```

The code I am trying is literally

```
import pytumblr
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of your `PYTHONPATH` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the error message says is that your python interpreter cannot find the `helper` module.

This module is defined in the `pytumblr` module, so I suspect you are in the `pytumblr` folder you cloned, which is why you can do

```
import pytumblr
```

But the path to the module is not in your `PYTHONPATH` variable, so python cannot find the `helper` module, which is deeper in the directory. (Try to go in the `pytumblr/pytumblr` directory, then launch python and `import helpers` will work).

What you need to do is add the top level repository where you put `pytumblr` to you `PYTHONPATH` (either doing `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:pytumblr_repo` or [How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7) if you are on windows).

You can also move `pytumblr` sources to a directory already in your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: I think I said that wrong. I have downloaded the files and are using them on my computer. My script is one directory above pytumblr and is calling the --init-- file. http://i.imgur.com/DWyZp3e.gif

Comment: Yes, and that is the problem, because `import` calls are relative to your location. You would need to call `import pytumblr.helpers` but the call that is made is `import helpers`. You need include the `pytumblr` folder to your `PYTHONPATH` or be inside this folder (in the same folder as the `helpers.py` file)

Comment: Sorry, I misused repository. I meant your local directory.

Comment: Ahh! Thanks! Do you mind explaining PYTHONPATH and PATH too? It now gives me an error trying to import a standard module that comes with Python.

Comment: Never mind. After all of your help I realized that this code wasn't written for Python 3. Turns out there are several Python 3 Tumblr API programs if I actually Google specfiically for Python 3. In any case, thank you for your help. I learned a bit and you were very helpful. :)

Comment: Glad to help, it is usefull for any package, python2 or python3 ;)